# Got arrested or Was arrested

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, american-english, descriptive-grammar

Not really sure how to use Get/Got + V3 or V.to be + V3 ( Passive voice )

Can anyone explain, are there any differences between these two grammar structures ?

Comment: There's a difference in "tone".  "Was arrested" is reasonably neutral, while "got arrested" is somewhat prejudicial.

Comment: Thank you, can this idea apply for other contexts as well ? like                                                         V. to be + V.3 always stands for something that is reasonably neutral while  Get/Got + V.3 always stands for something that is prejudicial.

Comment: Only a little.  Eg, there is some of the same tonal difference between "was cooked" and "got cooked", but the implications would be quite different.